# Rails ActiveRecord Create with file params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my app's `seeds.rb` I create a Template object used for testing purposes. Normally a Template is created through a form that requires a file uploaded with it. The file gets stored in S3 and the url gets added to the Template object as an attribute.

How can I pass in the file body and file name in my seeds file so the url gets correctly set on the Template object?

**seeds.rb**

```
# need to include params[:template][:body].tempfile
# and params[:template][:body].original_filename
template = user.templates.new(name: 'test_template.docx')
template.save
```

**templates_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    # upload to s3
    file_name = params[:template][:body].original_filename
    s3        = Amazon::S3.resource
    obj       = s3.bucket(User.directory_bucket).object(current_user.uuid + '/templates/' + file_name)

    obj.upload_file(params[:template][:body].tempfile)

    # create template
    @template = Template.create(name: file_name, url: obj.public_url, user_id: params[:template][:user_id])

    # redirects/response
  end
```

Comment: Do you want to store the file your referencing in the seeds.rb file in S3? Or are you hoping that the test_template.docx can just live locally?

Comment: I'd like to store the file in S3. The test data will be cleaned off there afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
user = ... # lookup the user you want to associate with

file_name = 'test_template.docx'
s3        = Amazon::S3.resource
obj       = s3.bucket(User.directory_bucket).object(user.uuid + '/templates/' + file_name)

obj.upload_file(File.new('path/to/' + file_name))

template = user.templates.new(name: file_name)
template.save
```